# How to use aiBringToFront in Illustrator Extendscript?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, extendscript

In Illustrator, I want to create a function in one of my scripts for *Bring to Front*.  In the CS5 Type Library, I find the object, `AiZOrderMethod.aiBringToFront`, however, I can't figure out how to use it.

Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
//BringToFront

mySelection = activeDocument.selection;
    if (mySelection.length>0){
        var doc = app.activeDocument;                   //current document
        var s    = doc.selection;                              //current slection
        var sl   = s.length;                                     //number of selected objects
        s.AiZOrderMethod.aiBringToFront();

        //for(var i = 0 ; i < sl; i++) s[i].aibringtofront();   //for each selected element...
        app.redraw();
    }else{
        alert("Nothing selected!")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.activeDocument.selection` is an `Array`

Try this:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;  //current document
var sel = doc.selection;       // array
var sl   = sel.length;       //number of selected objects

    if (sl>0){
        for(var i = 0 ; i < sl; i++){
            // for every item in selection array
          sel[i].zOrder(ZOrderMethod.BRINGTOFRONT);
            }
        app.redraw();
    }else{
        alert("Nothing selected!")
}
```

Comment: you can get the whole content of the ESTK Object Model Viewer for AI, ID and PSD here as .chm or .html files. It is much easier to browse http://www.jongware.com/idjshelp.html